# Laravel factory returns 0 for field, stores number in database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a laravel factory that looks like this:

```
$factory->define( Municipality::class, function ( Generator $faker ) {

    return [
        'name' => $faker->city,
        'number' => (int) $faker->numerify( '####' )
    ];

} );
```

If I run `php artisan tinker` and use the factory like this `factory(Acme\Models\Municipality::class)->create`, I get the output

```
=> Acme\Models\Municipality {#797
  name: "West Alysaland",
  number: 0,
}
```

When I run `Acme\Models\Municipality::all()` I get

```
>>> Municipality::all();
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#771
     all: [
       Acme\Models\Municipality {#798
         number: 9449,
         name: "Lake Rosemarie",
       },
     ],
   }
```

`number` is set as fillable in the model and the field is set to `unsignedInteger` in the migration.

Do anyone have any idea why this happens?

**Edit:**

After some debugging I found out that this happened after `->save()` was called on the model.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The model did not have an auto incrementing primary key, so I needed to set `public $incrementing = false;` in the model.

Comment: Thank you very much for returning and answering your own question